# Swift - Create a valid date for the current week given only the day of week as a String

Tags: swift, date, type-conversion

I need to create a valid date, for the current week (Sun - Sat) using only the day of the week.

For example:
The date today is Sept 17th, 2020. So the week range is Sunday Sept 13th - Saturday Sept 19th.

Given "Tuesday", I need to convert this string into this: Tuesday, September 15th, 2020 as type Date.

I've tried to do this but I come up with a very messy, unreliable solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't give you an answer (much less a *better* answer than you already have), but that's just my point - why not post your very messy, unreliable solution? While I don't know the date pickers, I do know Swift. Maybe all I could do is make your very messy solution more reliable, or maybe your unreliable solution less messy. Either way, I'm quite sure someone here could help you in both areas! (And either way, good luck.)

Comment: Show what you have. It may be easy to fix the messiness, but i can't imagine what could be unreliable about Calendar operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .weekOfYear], from: Date())
dateComponents.weekday = 1 // Figure out a way to map "Sunday" = 1, "Monday" = 2, etc..
let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"

print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!)) // Sunday, September 13, 2020
```

I'd probably look into creating an enum for the Weekdays. You could init it with a String value, and have a function to return the Int value for it.

```
enum Weekday: Int {
    case sunday = 1
    case monday = 2
    case tuesday = 3
    case wednesday = 4
    case thursday = 5
    case friday = 6
    case saturday = 7

    init?(_ stringValue: String) {
        switch stringValue {
        case "Sunday":
            self = .sunday
        case "Monday":
            self = .monday
        case "Tuesday":
            self = .tuesday
        case "Wednesday":
            self = .wednesday
        case "Thursday":
            self = .thursday
        case "Friday":
            self = .friday
        case "Saturday":
            self = .saturday
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it you'd do:

```
if let weekday = Weekday("Wednesday") {
    // ... code above
    dateComponents.weekday = weekday.rawValue
    // ... some more code 
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Great use of the enum. I learned a new way of problem solving with your solution. Thanks!